# How can I retrieve Value of SharedPreference file in another Activity?

Tags: java, sharedpreferences

```
Activity 1st..
Here this is my first activity to add data


preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                  preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                  editor = preferences.edit();
                 editor.putString("userid",et_username.getText().toString());//adduserid
                editor.putString("password",et_password.getText().toString());//add password
                  editor.commit();
```

Activity 2nd
This is my second activity to retrieve data.

```
String userName=preferences.getString("userid","");
            String password=preferences.getString("password","");
            Log.d("user : second", ""+preferences.getString("userid",""));
            Log.d("password : second", ""+preferences.getString("password",""));
```

Here Log is not displayed because of null value.

Comment: Is Log not displayed **at all** (due to NullPointerException maybe?) or is displayed without userid's value? How do you obtain preferences object in your second Activity?

Comment: @mit B could you try this ? and let me know the result.

Comment: @Adalarasan_Serangulam what should I try?? :)

Comment: @MitBhatt check my updated answer.. hope its useful..

Answer (score 0):

Check your `preferences` object (probably is `null`). That might be the problem, as the other String variables are never null, the can be empty string (`""`).

Are you missing the initialization of `preferences` in the second `Activity` just in this example?

Comment: Add "preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);" to your second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
String userName=preferences.getString("userid");
String password=preferences.getString("password");
Log.d("user : second", ""+userName);
Log.d("password : second", ""+password);
```

Could you please try this way.

Comment: getString() has always two parameters, key and DefValue... so this is not possible..

Answer (score 0):

In both activities just use this to get the SharedPreferences object:

`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

It may be that you attempt to access different preferences files from different Activities.

Or just use

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

i just store the one integer value you must more then one value in it..

```
PreferenceConnector.writeInteger(home.this, PreferenceConnector.com_id, homeComp_id);
```

below the `preferenceConnector` class to be use in it...

```
public class PreferenceConnector {

public static final String PREF_NAME = "Shared Preference";
public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public static final String com_id = "com_id";

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}

public static Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}

}
```

and then u also use the share preference value  to other activity like below...

```
 int Pref = PreferenceConnector.readInteger(mainpage.this, PreferenceConnector.com_id, 0);
```

hope above code to be useful...